# consulta o cursor en mysql

Tags: mysql, tsql

como puede ver no quiero que me muestro datos del mes de abril del 2018 pero si 
hay registros del mes de abril osea si existe fecha del mes de abril descarte ese paritemcod y
 pase al siguiente por que son 20 paritemcod de varios dni por que por cada dni hay 20 paritemcod 
espero su respuesta
gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que dejes el código y los resultados en forma de texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los otros usuarios, también te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y ver [ask] para mejorar tus preguntas y obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Pues no entiendo del todo la pregunta, pero cuando se trabaja con between agrupar las condiciones dentro de (), suele solucionar muchos problemas.